# Gulp: How to match all image file types

Tags: regex, gulp

I'm working on a Gulp build script to run jsHint, minimize/compress JS and CSS, move HTML files and other various build tasks.

I'd like to create a task to move all image files from a specific directory. Is there a generic pattern to match `.png`', `.gif`, `.jpg` and other common image file types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file name matching pattern would take whichever extensions you're after and put them in a case-insensitive or-ed group like this:

```
.*\.(?:jpg|gif|png|bmp)$
```

See here for a list of possible file extensions (if interested):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats#Stereo_formats